# Where to upload custom form.phtml?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides

I modified the text for the product review form but the website doesn't reflect the update.

I edited:

**vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

I put uploaded it to my custom theme at:

**app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

I cleared all my cache and deleted all the static theme files but when I refresh the button text is still the same.

My custom theme reference magento's blank theme as the parent.

Did I upload my modified file to the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom theme, the path should be: `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Review/templates/form.phtml`

You can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html